# populate hidden form field from another object in viewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I have a view that takes a view model (vm)
The vm has a ICollection<Conversation> Conversations
each Conversation has ICollection<Message> Messages. Message has a public virtual <Collection>.
There is also a <Message> NewMessage empty object in the vm so there are two top-level object classes in the vm.

vm.NewMessage and vm.Conversations

For-Each Conversation in Conversations I am displaying an input form to capture the NewMessage then For-Each through the Messages to display the current state of the conversation below the input form. (i.e. I have multiple forms on the page)

Each form has a hidden field which indicates which conversation it belongs to

```
foreach(cnv in Model.Conversations)
{
  @Html.BeginForm()
  {
      <fieldset>
          <legend>new message:</legend>
          @Html.LabelFor(nm => nm.NewMessage.MessageText)
          @Html.EditorFor(nm => nm.NewMessage.MessageText)
          @Html.HiddenFor(nm => nm.NewMessage.Conversation.ID )
          ... other form stuff like submit/clear form
      </fieldset>
  }
  ... do the stuff to display the current conversation
}
```

How do I populate the hidden value with the ID of the current Conversation, or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: how does your http post action looks like

Comment: haven't got that far yet :) but it will POST to a controller action that is expecting a <Message> object in the form post data, do the necessary to store the message in the database and trigger additional actions then will redirect to the original page which will now pick up the new message

Comment: does message object has a ConversationID property ?

Comment: yes, ConversationID is the FK that links the Conversation to the Message.  Whether I populate Message.ConversationID or Message.Conversation.ID is a moot point as my problem is actually getting the cnv.ID into the value field that I am struggling with.

Comment: Would `<input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="@cnv.ID">` work instead of using the `@Html.HiddenFor`?

Comment: Thanks Eric, pretty sure that would work, but it feels 'clunky' to context switch between helpers and hard-coded html text.  When using the helper and looking at the source code I see value="". I can use the format @html.HiddenFor(nm => nm.Message.Conversation.ID, new {Value = cnv,ID.ToString()}) but this still shows value="" and a new attribute Value="2" (note lowercase and uppercase V!) - just wondered how i populate the value rather than Value..

Answer (score 1):

Your current code will produce HTML markup like this for each item in the loop

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="NewComment_MessageText"
                                  name="NewComment.MessageText" type="text" value="">
```

So if your http post action method's parameter is `Message`, when the form is submitted, it will be null, as model binder cannot bind this form field values to the `Message` object. (*it will work with your current view model on which Message is a property*)

You should generate the below markup for model binder to work

```
<input class="text-box single-line" name="MessageText" type="text" value="">
```

You can do that by

```
foreach(cnv in Model.Conversations)
{
  @using(Html.BeginForm("SaveComment","YourControllerName"))
  {
      <fieldset>
          <legend>new message:</legend>
           @Html.Label("MessageText")
           @Html.TextArea("MessageText")
           @Html.Hidden("ConversationId",cnv.ID)
           <input type="submit" />
       </fieldset>
  }
  ... do the stuff to display the current conversation
}
```

The line `@Html.Hidden("ConversationId",cnv.Id)` will generate a hidden input field with name `ConversationId` and value from the expression `cnv.ID`

It should work assuming your HttpPost action methods' parameter is Message object and another one with the name `ConversationId` (Same as our input field name)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveComment(Message msg,int conversationId)
{
    // to do: return something
}
```

Comment: you are of course correct in that the model would not be recognised because the field names will not match.  How about if the ActionResult takes the vm as it's first argument.  Doing it in the way you propose means that the view is tightly bound to the model.  I am going to upvote the suggestion as it does fix the problem, but I am still interested in how   to force the value in the HiddenFor helper.

Comment: I personally prefer to create small lean view models with properties absolutely needed and use that in my ui layer ( so i can switch my data access layer at any time). In that approach, i would create a new class called NewMessage with 2 properties, `MessageText` and `ConversationId` and use that in my SaveComment method as parameter

Comment: I can see the appeal of that, but don't you lose some of the intrinsic benefits of the model based inheritance.  If the domain model changes, now you have to update the viewModel, view Form and the [HttpPost]ActionResult mapping as well as the base Model class and you lose any client-side validation based on annotations in the domain model.  Plus you end up with a specific ViewModel for every view and therefore don't benefit from as much code-reuse.

Comment: It is true that you may feel that there will be code duplication. But that allows you to build a loosely coupled system. If you use the Domain models in your view(ui layer), it is a tightly coupled system. What if your team decides to switch from Entity framework as the data access technology because they feel it is not fast enough ? Then you need to fix your UI code as well !!!! Keeping view models specific for your view seperate from your domain entities allows you to easily switch your data access layer without touching the UI layer